# Parse data from uploaded file check appropriate buttons fill in comments

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, csv

I am in need of some assistance. I've done a lot of searching up and down the internet to no avail. So I have been tasked with creating an upload function for my web application. The application is used to accept surveys from clients. The questions to the survey are presented via jquery, ajax/javascript, webservice, etc… each question has both a set of radio buttons “Yes” and “No” as well as a comment area-- I’ll include the html markup below. There are over 20 questions per survey.

What I am trying to do is create an upload button where data is parsed from a csv file and depending on the answers within the csv ("Yes" or "No" or Comments) it would check the appropriate radio button as well as fill in any comments if there are any. Here are some of my issues pertaining to this task;

1.The file we are attempting to upload has a bunch of data in it we don’t need as well as a bunch of extra “,”. I was wondering if there would be any way to find the data we need and disregard the data we don’t. *Note we cannot delete the data from the excel file we are using to create the csv as it is locked.

2.Would we need to save the file to the database first before parsing the data or can we have it parse the data without uploading to server as that would be more ideal?

Also I didn’t know if there were any nuget packages and or plugins that would help to make this task much easier. Any and all insight is welcomed.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="yesno-question-row" data-answerid="13228" style="font-weight: bold;">
    <span class="yesno-question">1) Is the 3TG intentionally added to your product?</span>
    <span class="yesno-answer">
        <span class="yesno-radio required">
            <input class="yesno-radio-button" type="radio" name="yesno13228" value="Yes" undefined="">Yes 
            <input class="yesno-radio-button" type="radio" name="yesno13228" value="No" undefined="">No
        </span>
        <span class="yesno-comment"> 
            <textarea class="yesno-textarea ui-widget-content"></textarea>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe there's some regular expression you can make to parse the csv file contents for only the parts you need. Getting the data back into the form should be trivial, select the correct nodes and change their value.

2) Concerning storing the file, both options work. You'll have to chose what's most appropriate for the project. If you only have an sql database, i'd parse the data on the client and just save the values in a sql table. 
If you have a file storage database and need for the file, you could store the entire file. 
If the file contains too much 'useless' data though, go for values only to save some bandwidth.

Note: Depending on what exactly you need, it might be advantageous to parse the csv to json.

Comment: Ideally I would like to parse the data and fill in appropriate radio buttons and comments. Once the data is read the client will then hit a submit button which would then submit the data to the server.